# mysql INSERTING values into database with certain date format using java prep statement

Tags: java, mysql, date

i am almost emberassed to ask this i am having trouble entering the query below, i want to enter a  date value with a different format (dd/mm/yy). mysql is tired and doesnt want to work with me entering a value, but in the wrong format. i put the string 03-08-2009 in a variable(java) and use ? prepared satement to execute the query .

```
INSERT INTO project (code, sdatum) VALUES(
            12, STR_TO_DATE('03-08-2009', '%d/%m/%Y'));
```

this is what mysql inserts into the column table

> '12','2009-08-03'

PS: i am using the workbench

Comment: So, what's the problem?  MySQL has done exactly what you asked.  If you want to retrieve dates formatted in some other way, you must use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in your select expression.

Comment: No, the year is very much in the right place.  [MySQL retrieves and displays `DATE` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html)

Comment: so if i open the database it wont display it in that format? only when i retrieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "*open the database*"?

Comment: mysql workbench man, i am using a local database with mysql workbench

Comment: But all MySQL workbench is doing is running `SELECT * FROM project` and showing you the results... if you want to run a different query, such as `SELECT code, DATE_FORMAT(sdatum, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM project` then that's what you should do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21105/discussion-between-hamchi-and-eggyal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

As documented under [The `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL retrieves and displays `DATE` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format.

If you want to retrieve dates formatted in some other way, you must apply [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to your select expression:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sdatum, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM project
```

Comment: You *did* insert data using a different format.  Internally, MySQL stores the date in some other format entirely and then converts it to its display format when you run a query.  You can't change the default date display format (without editing the source), but you can format expressions in your query as shown above.